# Using LINQ's ForEach with anonymous methods in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying to replace the classic `For Each` loop with the LINQ `ForEach` extension in VB.NET...

```
  Dim singles As New List(Of Single)(someSingleList)
  Dim integers As New List(Of Integer)

  For Each singleValue In singles
    integers.Add(CInt(Math.Round(singleValue)))
  Next singleValue
```

Maybe something like this?

```
  singles.ForEach(Function(s As [Single]) Do ???
```

How can I correctly do this using anonymous methods (i.e. without declare a new function)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
singles.ForEach(Sub(s As [Single]) integers.Add(CInt(Math.Round(s))))
```

You need a `Sub` here, because the body of your `For Each` loop doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 4):

Rather that using the `.ForEach` extension method, you can just directly produce the results this way:

```
Dim integers = singles.Select(Function(x) Math.Round(x)).Cast(Of Integer)()
```

Or without using `.Cast`, like this:

```
Dim integers = singles.Select(Function(x) CInt(Math.Round(x)))
```

It saves you from having to predeclare the `List(Of Integer)` and I also think it is clearer that you are simply applying a transformation and producing a result (which is clear from the assignment).

Note: this produced an `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` which can be used most places where you'd use a `List(Of Integer)`... but you can't add to it. If you want a `List`, simply tack on `.ToList()` to the end of the code samples above.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a Function if you expect the inline expression to return a value. For example:

```
Dim myProduct = repository.Products.First(Function(p) p.Id = 1)
```

This would use a Function expression, because it's something that evaluates to a Boolean (p.Id = 1).

You need to use a Sub because there is nothing being returned from the expression:

```
singles.ForEach(Sub(s) integers.Add(CInt(Math.Round(s))))
```

Comment: don't understand first code... finally you have `Dim myProduct = false` ?

Comment: Nope... it's the inner function that evaluates to Boolean, the outer function yields a Product. Was trying to show the distinction between the two uses; the First() method takes a predicate filter that evaluates each item to true/false - in this case looking for an item by Id. The ForEach operator iterates through performing an action but not returning anything.